# Lua: pattern matching multi-characters with the ? repetition operator

Tags: regex, lua, lua-patterns

According to [the docs](http://lua-users.org/wiki/PatternsTutorial), all Lua repetition operators only work on single characters, so you can match

```
string.match('123', '1?(%d+)') -- returns 23
```

but cannot match multi-character strings:

```
string.match('123', '(12)?(%d+)') -- want this to return 3
```

The docs say it's possible through "multiple patterns and custom logic", but I don't know what that means. Can someone offer a way to pattern match the above? Basically, `12` should be optionally matched all-or-nothing, and return the remainder of the digit string.

Comment: You can also try LPeg or lrexlib

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think "multiple patterns and custom logic" here means usage like this:

```
string.match('123', '12(%d+)') or string.match('123', '(%d+)')
```

Since `or` is short-circuit, if the first pattern matches, it will be the value of the expresion, otherwise the second pattern will try to match. This is exactly the regex `(12)?(%d+)` means.

Also note that there are more powerful [LPeg](http://www.inf.puc-rio.br/~roberto/lpeg/) or other regex libraries for Lua.